# How would I auto click for a Centos server?

Tags: centos

Is there any way to do auto clicking on CentOS? I have tried googling for a simple auto clicker and couldn't seem to find any (yet Ubuntu seemed to have promising results). Is there any well known auto clicker out there for CentOS? Or maybe is there a way to do it without even needing to install a program?

Answer (score 2):

Need unicorns, eh?
I would do this with `xdotool`. Try this:

```
xdotool click --repeat 9999 --delay 10 1
```

This will click the left mouse button 9999 times with a delay of 10 milliseconds.